# LIKE in Array of Objects in JSONB column

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

I have JSONB data in a Postgres column like this:

```json
{
  "Id": "5c6d3210-1def-489b-badd-2bcc4a1cda28",
  "Name": "Jane Doe",
  "Tags": [
    {
      "Key": "Project",
      "Value": "1004345"
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I query data where Name contains "Jane" or "Tags.Key" contains "4345"?

I tried this but this only matches the exact "Key" value:

```sql
select * from documents where data->'Tags' @> '[{ "Value":"1004345"}]';
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [JSON path](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-SQLJSON-PATH) operator using `like_regex`

```
select *
from documents
where data @@ '$.Tags[*].Value like_regex "4345"'
```

Comment: You forgot `data->>'Name' LIKE '%Jane%'` (_where Name contains "Jane"_)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name If you won't mind adding `or data->>'Name' LIKE '%Jane%'` I'll mark your answer as accepted.

Answer (score -1):

- you can do this way

```
select *
from documents
where 'Tags' ->> 'Value' = '1004345';
```